# How to add a legend with multiple groups in R?

Tags: r, legend

I have a scatterplot with three different colours and two different plotting symbols. Therefore, I need a legend with 6 objects/texts. My data has this format var1,var2,group1,group2.

How can I create the legend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the color, symbol and label for each of the six possibilities.

```
## Some bogus data
set.seed(2017)
x = runif(100)
y = runif(100)
COL = rep(1, 100)
COL[x< 1/3] = 2
COL[x> 2/3] = 3
Symb = rep(15, 100)
Symb[y<1/2] = 16

## Plot and legend
plot(x,y, pch=Symb, col=COL, xlim = c(0,1.15))
legend("topright", legend=LETTERS[1:6], col=1:3, pch=15:16)
```

[image: Plot with legend]